# Where is the data related to PHP version stored in Magento?

Tags: magento2, php, cron

I am new to Magento & learning it. I have installed **Magento 2.1.7** in different folder twice both are showing different errors for the same configuration in the same system.

First, I installed Magento in my system with folder name "magento2.1" & then changed the **php.ini** file **memory_limit=1024M**.

Secondly, I installed Magento with the name "magento_test" than when I am running both Magento installations & installing an extension named Instant search.

In magento 2.1 it is showing error like

[image: Magento 2.1 error]

In magento_test it is showing the below error

[image: Magento_test error]

Can anyone tell me why this is happening? My system has the Php 7.0.2 & I am using xampp in windows,& I was also getting the error of cron job in both the cases first for that I have skipped the cronjob checking By making.

```
$setupCheck = ['success'=>1];
$updaterCheck = ['success'=>1];
```

So the cron job is not there but I am facing the above-given errors can anyone tell me what to do?

Comment: First try to run these 3 cron manually from command promt:
<magento install dir>/bin/magento cron:run

<magento install dir>/update/cron.php

<magento install dir>/bin/magento setup:cron:run

and again try to install
ref: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html

Comment: hi @abhishek from the second screenshot i have faced the same issue at the earlier. just remove the comment for the required attribute in the php.ini ,  what attributes want to remove comment that will know when u click on show details. and restart the xampp server and try to install it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Emipro Technologies Pvt Ltd. your suggestion worked.
I am writing this answer in an appropriate manner for helping them who are using Windows system & trying to use it in localhost.

Simply go into your Magento directory & open command prompt there & type these three commands without doing any changes into your installation of Magento for installing the extension

```
php bin/magento cron:run
php update/cron.php
php bin/magento setup:cron:run
```

After this again reload your admin panel & try to install the extension into your system you will not get the error of the above listed.